# Errors in Gradle Sync [IntelliJ Idea 13.1]

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am running a Windows 8 machine and I wanted to have a go with Android development.

However, I am getting errors. The errors are as seen below:

[image: Error Message]

I dunno what I did wrong. Here are the configuration screens I used:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my android SDK configuration:

[image]

Please let me know if you guys can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are incorrect versions of some of your libraries specified in one of your **build.gradle** files. Find the build file where those libraries are specified; it should be in your module's directory.  Change the version number of the three dependencies it's throwing errors on to `20.0.+`.